# How to make a successful http request in Flutter web from a Python Cloud Function?

Tags: python, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I have a very basic python Cloud Function (with CORS enabled) that looks like :

```
@functions_framework.http
def function_with_cors_enabled(event):
    method = event.method
    endpoint = event.path
    route_key = method + " " + endpoint
    logging.info(f"Route key : {route_key}")
    if method == "OPTIONS":
        # Allows GET requests from any origin with the Content-Type
        # header and caches preflight response for an 3600s
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, X-AppCheck',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }
        return '', 204, headers

    # Set CORS headers for the main request
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    }
    if route_key == "GET /test":
        return test_call(), 200, headers
    return {"error": "not allowed"}, 401

def test_call():
    logging.info("Test !")
    return {"message", "success"}
```

I have tried all combination of return :

- `return test_call(), 200, headers` to match with the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-http-functions#cors)
- `return test_call(), headers` with `test_call()` returning the status code in addition of the `dict`
- `return test_call()` without `headers`
- And so on...

When i check my Cloud Logging logs, i do see everything successfully running in python the the `Test !` log with the return status code 200.

In Flutter web i do see an undefined error :

```
ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error., uri=https://mycloud_function_endpoint
```

How to make a successful http request in flutter web from a python cloud function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to simply add :

`headers = event.headers` in the top of the function :

```
@functions_framework.http
def function_with_cors_enabled(event):
    method = event.method
    endpoint = event.path
    headers = event.headers # this line
    route_key = method + " " + endpoint
    logging.info(f"Route key : {route_key}")
    if method == "OPTIONS":
        # Allows GET requests from any origin with the Content-Type
        # header and caches preflight response for an 3600s
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, X-AppCheck',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }
        return '', 204, headers

    # Set CORS headers for the main request
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    }
    if route_key == "GET /test":
        return test_call(), 200, headers
    return {"error": "not allowed"}, 401
```

That means flutter web expect some headers from the function in addition of the ones i have added here.